# Slope of circle at any given angle

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to find the slope of a circle at any give angle? Is there a formula and is the range for the slope is R + infinity?

Comment: Did you have tried? At what point?

Comment: Im trying derivative of circle but I dont know how to evaluate

Comment: The slope of the ray through $(0,0)$ and $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ (which is at an angle $\theta$ from the positive $x$-axis) is $m=\tan\theta$. The circle's tangent line at $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ has opposite reciprocal slope because it is perpendicular to the ray, $m'=-\cot\theta$.

Comment: Re Nightflight's answer, $y = 0$ corresponds to a tangent line with an *infinite* slope which actually signifies a vertical tangent line.

Comment: Thank you guys now I understand. That was actually easy lol. I made a simple thing complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the radius of the circle, there is a tangent of a circle with an arbitrary slope.

Let the equation of the circle se $x^2+y^2=R^2$, then use implict devivative.

Then we can get $2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, so $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac xy$.

Let $(x,y)=(R\cos t, R\sin t)$, and the slope as $m$.

Then $m=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac xy=-\cot t$. so $t=-\cot^{-1}m$.